# Threading + GUI (Tkinter)

Tags: python, tkinter, hilos

Estoy haciendo una interfaz de usuario con python, tengo por un lado la GUI realizada en Tkinter y un Main program que me devuelve los valores que voy a mostrar en dicha interfaz pero tengo un problema y es que el programa es un poco lento por lo que tome la decisión de implementar Threading, realice el programa que consta de:

- Thread 1: Leer sensores.
- Thread 2: Guardar valores en un documento de
  texto por cada sensor.

Pero aquí viene mi pregunta, ya que no se como devolver esos valores a mi Script de la interfaz.

Anteriormente mi programa era de esta forma:

```
def MainProgram(direcciones):
datosSensor=[]
for i in range(len(direcciones)):
    direccion=direcciones[i]
    datos=ReadInformation.Read(direccion)
    SaveInformation.Savetxt(datos)
    datosSensor.append(datos)
return datosSensor
```

Simplemente llamaba esa función a mi programa del GUI, pero cuando implemento threading intente hacer un thread que me devuelva el valor pero simplemente queda y no corre mas el programa, el código siguiente es el que implemente los threads pero sin el de return datos porque no se bien como debo hacerlo.

```
def read_sensor(direccion):
ReadInformation.init()
while True:
    shared_memory_guard.acquire()
    for i in direcciones:
        data=ReadInformation.Read(i)
        information.append(data)
    print("Read")
    shared_memory_guard.release()

def save_sensor(datos):
while True:
    shared_memory_guard.acquire()
    print("save")
    for j in datos:
        SaveInformation.Savetxt(j)
    del information[:]
    shared_memory_guard.release()  
direcciones = ScanAddress.address()
print('Creating threads')
t = threading.Thread(target=read_sensor, args=(direcciones,))
t2 = threading.Thread(target = save_sensor, args=(information,))
print('Executing read data thread')
t.start()
print('Executing file writer thread')
t2.start()
```

Espero que puedan ayudarme.

Answer (score 1):

Efectivamente tienes que realizar threading para que tu interfaz no se bloquee al usar tkinter. Espero te sirva lo siguiente.

En este ejemplo (tiene un detalle con los nombres de archivos con acentos, pero funciona) se simula que se abre un archivo para desencriptar y se actualiza el progreso con una barra y mensajes. Es python 2, pero seguro sabrás adaptarlo y arreglarlo:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import os

import Tkinter 
import ttk
import tkMessageBox
import tkFileDialog

import threading
import Queue
import subprocess

#import sys
import time


class Tareas():

    # propiedades de la ventana
    def __init__(self, parent, row, column, columnspan):
        self.parent = parent

        # tamaño de la ventana
        self.length=200
        self.value=0
        self.maximum=100
        self.interval=10

        # config de la barra de progreso
        self.barra_progreso = ttk.Progressbar(parent, orient=Tkinter.HORIZONTAL,
                                            length = self.length,
                                           mode="determinate",
                                           value=self.value,
                                           maximum=self.maximum)
        self.barra_progreso.grid(row=row, column=column,
                              columnspan=columnspan)

        # etiqueta status interfaz
        self.lbl_estado = Tkinter.Label(parent, text='STATUS:')
        self.lbl_estado.grid(row=9, column=0, padx = 20, pady = 5)

        # mensaje etiqueta estado de las tareas
        self.estado_aplicacion = Tkinter.StringVar()
        self.estado_aplicacion.set("Started, waiting for a task...")

        # etiqueta que muestra tareas
        self.lbl_info_estado = Tkinter.Label(parent, text=self.estado_aplicacion.get(), textvariable=self.estado_aplicacion)
        self.lbl_info_estado.grid(row=10, column=0, padx = 20, pady = 5)


    def extraerDatosArchivo(self):
        print 'tarea 1'

        # realiza una tarea antes de iniciar el thread
        self.estado_aplicacion.set('Seleccionando respaldo válido... (1/6)')

        tkMessageBox.showinfo('INFORMATION', 'Select file to decrypt.')

        self.archivo_respaldo = tkFileDialog.askopenfile(initialdir="/home/pagana", title="Select file", filetypes=(("All files", "*.*"), ("All files2", "*.*")) )

        print 'archivo a desencriptar: ', self.archivo_respaldo

        if self.archivo_respaldo is None or not self.archivo_respaldo:
            tkMessageBox.showerror('ERROR', 'No seleccionó nada.')
            return

        # --- reconfigurar la barra de progreso ---

        # reconfigurar la barra en 6+1 pasos
        # porque el primer paso ya fue hecho (value=1)
        self.barra_progreso.configure(maximum=7,
                                      value=1)

        # --- iniciar el threading

        # crear cola para comunicar/enviar tareas al thread
        self.queue = Queue.Queue()

        # crear el thread y enviar tarea 
        self.thread = threading.Thread(target=self.my_function, args=(self.queue,))

        # iniciar thread
        self.thread.start()

        # iniciar la cola de tareas  
        self.check_queue()


    def check_queue(self):
        print("checking queue")

        # revisar la cola para evitar bloque en la interfaz
        if not self.queue.empty():
            # obtener mensaje de la cola
            text = self.queue.get()
            print("get text from queue:", text)

            # cambar mensaje de status de tareas
            self.estado_aplicacion.set(text)

            # actualizar la barra de progreso 
            self.barra_progreso['value'] += 1

            # revisar si es el último mensaje de las tareas
            if text == 'TASKS FINISHED':
                # detener barra progreso
                self.barra_progreso.stop()

                # mostrar mensaje tarea completada y salir
                tkMessageBox.showinfo('INFORMATION', 'Done!.')
                return None

                #si algo fallo mostrar error
            elif text == 'ERROR':
                self.barra_progreso.stop()
                tkMessageBox.showerror('INFORMATION', 'ERROR!.')
                return None

        # revisar si hay tareas por hacer cada 200ms (0.2s)
        root.after(200, self.check_queue)


    def my_function(self, queue):

        # cambiar status
        queue.put('Copiando clave privada... (2/6)')

        nombre_respaldo = self.archivo_respaldo.name
        print 'nombre respaldo: '+nombre_respaldo

        # realizar una tarea
        time.sleep(4)
        print '2'

        # cambiar status
        queue.put('Creando carpeta de trabajo... (3/6)')

        # echar otra tarea
        time.sleep(4)
        print '3'

        # uff... algo se revento
        #queue.put('ERROR')
        #return #detener las tareas

        # cambiar status
        queue.put('Creando carpeta de trabajo... (4/6)')

        # y otra tarea
        time.sleep(4)
        print '4'

        # cambiar status
        queue.put('Creando carpeta de trabajo... (5/6)')

        # ya mero...
        time.sleep(4)
        print '5'


        # cambiar status
        queue.put('Creando carpeta de trabajo... (6/6)')

        # la ultima...
        time.sleep(4)
        print '6'

        # al fin...
        queue.put('TASKS FINISHED')


class GUI(Tkinter.Frame):
    """ clase para definir la GUI"""

    def __init__(self, parent,):
        Tkinter.Frame.__init__(self, master=parent)

        # posicionamiento del boton
        tareas = Tareas(parent, row=8, column=0, columnspan=2)

        # config del boton
        btn_extraer_datos_archivo = Tkinter.Button(parent, text = 'Select file', width=24, height=2, command=tareas.extraerDatosArchivo, state='normal')
        btn_extraer_datos_archivo.grid(row=2, column=0, padx = 40, pady = 5)

# --- main ---

root = Tkinter.Tk()

root.title('Extractor de datos 1.0')
root.minsize(200, 200)
root.resizable(0,0)

herramienta = GUI(root)
root.mainloop()
```

Si te das cuenta la interfaz no se bloquea y puedes cerrar la aplicación sin problema (que es lo que necesitas).

Tal vez igual puedas usar pyqt o pygtk, pero desconozco si con ellos esté cubierta la parte de threading o tú debas resolverlo también.